# Debugging memory usage in a very short lived application without Windows

Tags: debugging, .net-core

I have a console application that runs for less than 500ms, but that according to BenchmarkDotNet allocates more than 100 MB.

I am trying to figure out what are those 100Mb because it does not add up. However I cannot find a tool to do so in Linux or Mac. Once the method the app calls is over, the GC can clean all that memory without problems, so it is not a leak I can see in a dump, unless I take the dump in the very exact moment before exiting the method. I am not clear which is the moment in which the algorithm peaks in memory usage.

I can take CPU traces using `dotnet-trace` and show it in the browser with Speedscope, but I cannot show in Speedscope a trace when using  `gc-verbose` or `gc-collect` as provider.

Is there a way with `dotnet-trace` to print in the console the stats of the created objects or anything like that?

Comment: https://michaelscodingspot.com/dotnet-trace/

Answer (score 0):

try out dotnet dump and checkout this article by [Tess Ferrandez](https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2021/03/18/debugging-a-netcore-memory-issue-with-dotnet-dump.html).

and maybe you can share a little bit more information please.

Comment: That is the very thing I said I cannot do :D